# PHP 5.3.3 Not Detected in Piwik

Tags: php, matomo

I am trying to install the latest version of Piwik (2.8.3) on CentOS 6.5 with httpd. SELinux is set to Permissive mode. I am running PHP 5.3.3.

I have copied all the files required for Piwik, and I am able to load the installation page for Piwik, but on the installation requirements page, it says everything is good except for the line that says

"PHP version 5.3.3 PHP version > 5.3.3 : Error: PHP version > 5.3.3 required"

I know for a fact that I have PHP 5.3.3 installed because I can run the PHP function phpinfo(); and it says I am running PHP 5.3.3.

I thought it might have been an SELinux issue or some kind of permissions issue, but even when SELinux is set to permissive, this is a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when trying to install Piwik 2.8.3 and I also have PHP 5.3.3 installed.  To get around it just modify the php check file so if the PHP version is above 5.3.2 it will install.

[Here is a link to the Code you need to change](http://decken-it.com/piwik-gives-error-php-version-5-3-3-required-during-install/)

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Should we file a bug report with Piwik?

Comment: Yes good catch @DecKen, I've created an issue (https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/6595) and will fix it soon! Thanks